# Use join inside joined-subclass in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I've got hibernate mapping with joined subclass:

```
<joined-subclass name="CSomeClass"
          extends="CParentClass"
          table="some_class">

    <key column="id" />
    .....
</joined-subclass>
```

And I want to add there property that uses join:

```
<join table="another_class" optional="true" inverse="true">
    <subselect>SELECT owner_id, id FROM another_class WHERE owner_type = 4</subselect>
    <key column="owner_id"/>
    <many-to-one name="another" class="..." column="id" unique="true" lazy="proxy"/>
</join>
```

Is there any way to do that without changing joined-subclass to something else?(because I don't want to change not my code) Or maybe change somehow that everything would work like for joined-subclass now

UPD
My Hibernate version is 3.5 and I can't change it
[image: error]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Thomas it's says it's not allowed to do so: https://i.gyazo.com/3ac3937a649339cbbcdca3e6feca15f1.png

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the xml configuration, but assuming you want to have a relation to another entity, why don't you use `many-to-one` directly inside the subclass definition? Afaik you'd use `<class ...><many-to-one .../></class>` so I'd assume it should be `<joined-subclass ...><many-to-one .../></joined-subclass>`. Maybe you could provide a [mcve] for your model, it's hard to understand with all those omissions.

Comment: @Thomas that's because we had to move link into AnotherClass mapping, so now I am trying to remove it from another side in order not to store it twice. First I tried many-to-one with formula property instead of column, but it always dies with exception :(